# Generate subset of series {1,3,9,27,....} and order the subsets in increasing order of sum

Tags: java, algorithm, numbers, set

I am asked to generate subsets of the 3-power set {1,3,9,27,81,....} and then arrange the subsets in increasing order of their sum , for example { {},{1},,{3},{1,3},{9},{1,9},{3,9},{1,3,9},..........} . finally when the user inputs n , we need to print the nth subset , for example if n=4 , the solution is third subset {1,3}. the range of n is substantially very large .

My doubt is :

1. how do we arrive at the upper limit for the main set .
2. Which data structure should I use
3. Is there any approach other than a brute force.

Comment: Added category "algorithm"

Comment: Your problem looks like 'Counting in base 3'. Hence, I think that there is a better solution than brute force.

Comment: I'm a beginner , if someone can guide me on how should I proceed

Comment: In your example output you are missing the sets `{3}` and `{9}`

Answer (score 4):

For this problem, powers of 3 or powers of 2 are the same but it is easier to see the solution with powers of 2. See the sequence :

- {} sum : 0
- {1} sum : 1
- {2} sum : 2 (10 in binary)
- {1, 2} sum : 3 (11 in binary)
- {4} sum : 4 (100 in binary)
- {4, 1} sum : 5 (101 in binary)
- {4, 2} sum : 6 (110 in binary)

Hence, the solution is to count in binary then interpret the given numbers in base 3. Ex :

- 0 -> {}
- 1 -> 3^0 -> {1}
- 10 -> 3^1 -> {3}
- 11 -> 3^1, 3^0 -> {3, 1}
- 100 -> 3^2 -> {9}
- 101 -> 3^2, 3^0 -> {9, 1}
- 110 -> 3^2, 3^1 -> {9,3}
- 111 -> 3^2, 3^1, 3^0 -> {9,3,1}
- 1000 -> 3^3 -> {27}

So, for a given `n`, convert it to binary, then to ternary like above.

This is the **code** :

```
private static String calc(int n) {
  String binary = Integer.toString(n - 1, 2);
  String reverse = new StringBuilder(binary).reverse().toString();

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.append("{");
  for (int i = 0; i < reverse.length(); i++) {
    if(reverse.charAt(i) == '1') {
      sb.append(BigInteger.valueOf(3).pow(i)).append(" ");
    }
  }
  //remove last space
  if(sb.length() != 1) { sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() -1); }
  sb.append("}");
  return sb.toString();
}
```

**Test** :

```
for(int i = 1; i<=10; i++) {
  System.out.println(calc(i));
}
```

**Result** :

```
{}
{1}
{3}
{1 3}
{9}
{1 9}
{3 9}
{1 3 9}
{27}
{1 27}
```

Comment: This seems to be correct to me. Only thing is that according to OP's convention you will need to subtract 1 from n and then apply your binary conversion.

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not create a large set of subsets first, then sort it. You create the subsets in already-sorted order (this is the key part of the algorithm). You then return when you've created 'n' subsets.
2. You need to make your own. If i recall correctly, i simply used queues when i made something similar.
3. Not that i know of. The problem is that you need to order subsets, which isn't trivial.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any approach other than a brute force.

Yes there is. Try to generate the ordered sequence of sets. We can prove that this will work using induction.

1. The set with minimum sum is {}
2. Let assume that you have ordered all subsets containing numbers bellow N.
3. To generate all subsets containing N simply add N to each set from step 2 (in the same order)

This will work because the following is true - 3^n > 3^n-1 + 3^n-2 .... E.g the subset sum({3^n}) is greater than the sum of all subsets containing only 3^n-1 and smaller element.

**EXAMPLE**

1. {1} is the smallest subset
2. {}, {1}, {3}, {1,3}, {9}, {1,9}, {3,9}, {1,3,9} - the ordered subsets containing numbers less than 9
3. {}, {1}, {3}, {1,3}, {9}, {1,9}, {3,9}, {1,3,9}, {27}, {1,27}, {3,27}, {9,27} .... {1,3,9,27} - the ordered subsets containing numbers less than 27

Answer (score 0):

We just need to **convert the given 'n' to binary** then raise the power of **3^i** (for the ith bit **only if it is a setbit**) because only setbits will contribute to the subset.

This will work because of the condition: (3^n > 3^n-1 + 3^n-2)
eg: 3^2 > 3^1 + 3^0

now the code:

```
void decimalToBinary(long int n) 
{ 
int binaryNum[32];                        // array to store binary number  
int i = 0;                                // counter for binary array
while (n > 0) {                           // storing remainder in binary array
    binaryNum[i] = n % 2; 
    n = n / 2; 
    i++; 
} 
for (int j = 0; j <i; j++) 
{
    if(binarray[j]==1)
        cout<<binpower(3,j)<<" ";              //must be binary exponentiation
}
}
```

Input : 6

Output : 3 9

Comment: don't forget to use binary exponentiation

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily seen that the subset can be generated by printing  the i th   element of the set S if the i th bit is set in the binary representation of n and do not printing anything if the bit is not set.

1. Initialize count=0 and x=0
2. a vector for storing the elements of subsets
3. Do the following till n exits

   - set x=n&1 // for finding that that the last bit is set or not
   - now do this if x is not zero

     - push elements in vector by pow(3,count)
   - then do one right shift on n (n=n>>1)
   - increase the count value by 1
4. Finally print the elements of vector